# sql Number of Rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables with these columns:

**Table 1**:

```
ID ,   INT
NAME,  NVARCHA
ROLL,  INT
```

**Table 2**:

```
ID,        INT 
NAME_ID,   INT
REAL_DATE, Date
H7_00,     BIT
H8_00,     BIT
```

I want to get a list of names of those that H7_00 is true like this, for a period of 3 months.

```
Real_Date | Name| Name | Name | Name | Name | Name | Name |Name |Name |Name |Name   
Real_Date | Name    | Name |
Real_Date | Name| Name | Name | Name    
Real_Date | Name    | Name | Name | Name |Name| Name | Name | Name
```

The following is what I tried

```
SELECT 
    Hours.Real_Date, Person.Name ,Person.Role 
FROM  
    Person
INNER JOIN
    Hours ON Hours.P_ID = Person.ID
WHERE 
(Hours.Real_Date >=  getDate())
    AND
(Hours.Real_Date <=  getDate() + 90)
    (Hours.H7_00 = 1   AND  Hours.H7_00_Free = 1)
    AND 
    (Person.Role = 1)
ORDER BY 
    Real_Date, Name
```

This is what I got

```
 2013-12-12   AAAA  1
 2013-12-12   BBBB  1           
 2013-12-12   CCCC  1
```

If anyone has a solution I would appreciate it very,

And thanks in advance for reply

Answer (score 0):

In SQL-Server (TSQL) you can try it with [`DATEADD (datepart , number , date)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```sql
(DATEADD(DAY,0,Hours.Real_Date) >= DATEADD(DAY,0,getDate()))
AND
(DATEADD(DAY,0,Hours.Real_Date) <= DATEADD(DAY,+90,getDate()))
```

Comment: Which way it's supposed to help me?
I need to get some answers into one answer